# Why multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I have created applicationContext with two PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer beans and accessing only one based on my input using context object. But, while accessing for the properties from "Service2Record" instance I am getting "Service1Record" properties values. Below is my sample code.

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<beans >

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.record" />

<!-- Service1 Properties files -->
<bean id="service1"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations" >
        <value>classpath:service_1.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="properties" >
        <value>service1.class=com.test.record.ServiceRecord</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="service1record" class="${service1.class}" />

<!-- Service2 Properties files -->
<bean id="service2"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:service_2.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="properties">
        <value>service2.class=com.test.record.ServiceRecord</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="service2record" class="${service2.class}" />
```

**ServiceRecord Bean : -**

```
@Configuration
```

public class ServiceRecord {

```
@Value("${request_queue_name}")
private String requestQueueName;

@Value("${reply_queue_name}")
private String replyQueueName;

public String getRequestQueueName() {
    return requestQueueName;
}

public String getReplyQueueName() {
    return replyQueueName;
}
```

}

**Test Main Class -**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
    ServiceRecord serviceRecord = null;
    String inputService = "SERVICE2";
    if(inputService.equals("SERVICE1")){
        serviceRecord = (ServiceRecord)context.getBean("service1record");
    } else {
        serviceRecord = (ServiceRecord)context.getBean("service2record");
    }
    System.out.println(" RequestQueueName : " + serviceRecord.getRequestQueueName());

}
```

And

**service_1.properties**

```
request_queue_name=SERVICE1.REQUEST
```

reply_queue_name=SERVICE1.REPLY

**service_2.properties**

```
request_queue_name=SERVICE2.REQUEST
```

reply_queue_name=SERVICE2.REPLY

Here, every time output is "RequestQueueName : SERVICE2.REQUEST".  Can you please tell how to get the respective values based on the properties file?

**Modified** -

I have single PPHC, within that setting multiple prop files for the location property and multiple propertieArray as below.

```
<property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:common-service.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:search-service.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:update-service.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="propertiesArray" >
            <list>
                <value>common.class=com.xyz.rabbitmq.record.CommonUtil</value>
                <value>search.class=com.xyz.rabbitmq.record.SearchRecord</value>
                <value>update.class=com.xyz.rabbitmq.record.UpdateRecord</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    <bean id="commonrecord" class="${common.class}"/>
<bean id="searchrecord" class="${search.class}"/>
<bean id="updaterecord" class="${update.class}"/>
```

Here, keys are different in each properties file and getting the bean instance based on the search or update request type.

serviceRecord = (ServiceRecord)context.getBean("searchrecord");

Will this approach is correct for loading different files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use different keys in the properties files:

`service_1.properties`

```
service1.request_queue_name=SERVICE1.REQUEST
service1.reply_queue_name=SERVICE1.REPLY
```

`service_2.properties`

```
service1.request_queue_name=SERVICE2.REQUEST
service1.reply_queue_name=SERVICE2.REPLY
```

And different ServiceRecord files, `ServiceRecord1.java` `ServiceRecord2.java` each reads properites from relevant properites file. i.e. when a new properties set/file is added you need to add a new ServiceRecord file.

If you don't want to have multiple ServiceRecords, you can instead have a Util method ..

```
public String getProperty(String serviceName, String propertyName) {
    return propertySource.getProperty(serviceName+"."+propertyName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bean PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html). Before the beans will be created, it is called and modify the whole context (the definitions that can change), in this case, only one bfpp can change something. [Here](http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-bean-post-processors-and-beanFactory-post-processors.html) you can read more about this.

Comment: Am sorry, what does it mean here, only one BeanFactoryPostProcessor? Can you please tell me what chahes I need to make in applicationContext.xml file. FYI, am using Spring 3.2.x release version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two BeanFactoryPostProcessor do the same thing (exactly the same thing because the keys are the same) so once one make the change the other cann´t do anything. Test it adding the property <property name="order" value="<differents values>"></property> to the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: added order property for each PPHC,   
<property name="order" value="1"/> -=> PPHC1
<property name="order" value="2"/>  => PPHC2

but still am getting 1st property values. Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is that you can not use two PPHC for this case, because only one replace the keys, you need to change your strategy. For example, using differents keys, use a factory bean for generate your service class, or something different, depends what is your situation.

Comment: modified query with single PPHC with multiple properties files, will that be the right approach?

Comment: For your modified Problem: How does your CommonUtil know that it has to take properties from common-service.properties?

Comment: CommonUtil bean proerties will match to the keys in the common-service.properties file. Like,

host.name=localhost

@Value("${host.name}")
private String hostName;

Comment: I think this approach is better. I expect this solution resolve your problem.